# What is "i" in "function(i)" in the following JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following code there is "function(i)", but "i" hasn't been declared anywhere previous to this statement.

```
ul.css({width: 10, overflow: 'visible'}).retarder(100, function(i){
   i.css('visibility',  'visible').animate(
      {width: ul[0].wid,left:-50},
      {duration: 500, complete : function(){
         ul.css('overflow',  'visible');
      }}
   );
});
```

It looks like it could be similar to a c++ "this" statement.  Is that correct at all?

Comment: That's a anonymous function as a argument. Thus i is the first argument the function accepts. The retarder method calls the function say, callback(10, 11, 12), and thus provides a value for i. In this case i = 10 and everything else is discarded.

Comment: By the way, `i` is a horrible name for that argument, change it to something descriptive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`i` is just a function parameter that is passed by `retarder` function to the anonymous function.

What it does is:

```
ul.css({width: 10, overflow: 'visible'}).retarder(100, callback_function);
```

and callback is defined via anonymous function:

```
function(i) { ... }
```

So that `i` is definition of the parameter of the anonymous function.

Answer (score 12):

It looks like a function declaration:

```
function(i)
{
  // .....
}
```

So `i` is a value being passed into the function (which is being declared inline as an *anonymous function*) as its first parameter, presumably by the inner workings of the `retarder` method that you're passing the function into.

Re-writing the code so it's a *bit* more readable makes this a bit clearer:

```
ul.css(
  {
    width: 10, 
    overflow: 'visible'
  }
).retarder(100, function(i)
  { 
    i.css('visibility', 'visible').animate(
      {
        width: ul[0].wid,
        left:-50
      },
      {
        duration: 500, 
        complete: function()
          { 
            ul.css('overflow', 'visible'); 
          }
       } 
    );
  }
 );
```

And you can then rewrite it to be *even* clearer:

```
ul.css(
  {
    width: 10, 
    overflow: 'visible'
  }
).retarder(100, functionToPassToRedtarder);

function functionToPassToRetarder(i)
{
  i.css('visibility', 'visible').animate(
    {
      width: ul[0].wid,
      left:-50
    },
    {
      duration: 500, 
      complete: functionToPassToComplete
    } 
  );
}

function functionToPassToComplete()
{
    ul.css('overflow', 'visible'); 
}
```

Comment: @Aviral, yeup, exactly,... =)

Answer (score 7):

It's a function parameter.

Comment: why the downvote? The answer is certainly correct, even if it's not detailed. Explain yourself.

Comment: +1 upvoted for the sake of missing comment from downvoter :-)

Comment: Thank you. This is the third time that this happens to me today. It's really annoying.

Comment: Haha and now your answer is better than mine. What a fool I was :-))))

Comment: Technically, its a parameter: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_science)#Parameters_and_arguments

Answer (score 5):

it creates an anonymous function which take a single argument, which is then to be referred to as `i` in the function.

Comment: If you want to get technical, the function *formally* takes a single parameter. Conceivably you can pass many **arguments** and access them via an object of the same name.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you may not understand this is if you are unfamiliar with the use of anonymous functions in JavaScript. You are probably more familiar with something like:

```
function double(i){
    return i + i;
}
```

`i` is a parameter to the function `double`. In JavaScript, the same function could be done like:

```
var double = function(i){
    return i + i;
};
```

In this case an anonymous function is created and then assigned to a variable `double`. `i` is still just a parameter. Both can then be called like `double(3)`.

In the example you provided, instead of assigning the anonymous function to a variable, it was passed as an argument to another function.

Answer (score 1):

The variable i in the anonymous function declaration function(i) is the name used for the first parameter inside the function body. It does not correspond to any variable elsewhere in your page.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to decode the obfuscated code that I think you are, then you are probably looking for this function definition...

```
$.fn.retarder = function(delay, method){ 
var node = this; 
if (node.length){ 
    if (node[0]._timer_) 
        clearTimeout(node[0]._timer_); 
    node[0]._timer_ = setTimeout(function(){ method(node); }, delay); 
} 
return this; };
```

I had to dig a little deeper to find it because it was generated dynamically within an eval().

So to answer your question, the "i" parameter is the "ul" object (in the code you posted).

If you look at the retarder function it returns "this", just like most other jquery plugins, so it maintains chain-ability of plugins.

isn't de-obfuscating fun?

Answer (score 0):

The variable `i` represents the actual object (like keyword `this`)

---

Explain more:

1) Is a parameter to an anonymous function, as we can see:

```
.retarder(100, function(i){...})
```

2) Is a reference to current object (`this`).

When this jquery plugin finishes, it calls the callback function, using:

```
(callbackFunction)(this)
```

Where this is parameter.

Comment: As everyone else has mentioned, it is a parameter to an anonymous function.

Comment: Buddy, yes, is a parameter to an anonymous function...but, in this case, is a parameter that represents the actual object = this.